# Error while trying to retain previous value on $set mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
await ProjectModel.findOneAndUpdate(
{
  _id:projectId,
  users:{$elemMatch: { user: userUpdate.user }}
},
{
   $set: {
         'users.$.role': override? userUpdate.role:'$users.$.role'
        }
})
```

On executing this for override false[mongodb output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3qni.png)

I want to retain the original role data if override is false .
Appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, you can't use `$` to refer the field in MongoDB update query. But based on what I understand your logic, you could just only execute the update query when `override` is true. `if (override) { /* execute update logic */ }`